# How to prevent HTML button from clicking if already running JS

Tags: javascript, html, button, boolean, progress-bar

I am wondering how I might be able to stop a button clicking if the function it is performing is running. Here is my JS code:

```js
let money = 0;
let running = false;

function start(time, val) {
  if (running == false) {
    running = true;
    console.log(running)
    let bar = document.getElementById('progressBar1');
    bar.value = time;
    time++;
    let sim = setTimeout("start(" + time + ")", 30);
    if (time == 100) {
      bar.value = 0;
      let id = val;
      money++;
      document.getElementById("moneyValue").innerHTML = money;
      clearTimeout(sim);
      running = false;
    }
  } else if (running == true) {
      console.log("Already Growing!");
  };
}
```

```html
<progress id="progressBar1" value="0" max="100" style="width:150px;"></progress>
<button id="restart-button" class="plantBtn" onclick="start(0, this.id)">Plant Seed</button>
```

What it does is start a progress bar (progress div). I want the button to alert a message saying already going or something like that.

The issue I am having is that it is jumping to the else if statement, and not running anything. The odd thing is that if I add a `console.log` into the middle of the if statement it works.

I think it is because the bar takes time to fill, it will never reach full if the user clicks it, because it will jump to the else if statement and cancel out the if function. (It only becomes false again after the bar reaches 100%)

Can anyone help? I am open to JS or Jquery (bit rusty on that tho).

Thanks

Comment: You have an extra curly brace; instead of `} else if (running == true) {` you just need `else if (running == true) {`

Comment: No, that brace is linked to the other if statement (inside the first)

Comment: Why are you calling the same function? The code after the timeout should be called with the timeout, not calling the logic that starts it

Comment: what? It is each time a button is clicked. So the button will be clicked multiple times but I don't want it to do the action until the previous one has finished

Comment: @epascarello could you demonstrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the button clicking, not the actual `start` function that you need to call it from by the timer. So it's better to separate these functions:

```js
let money = 0;
let running = false;

// when clicking the button
function onClickButton(time, val) {
  if(running) {
    console.log("Already Growing!");
  } else {
    running = true;
    start(time, val);
  }
}

// timer function
function start(time, val) {
  let bar = document.getElementById('progressBar1');
  bar.value = time;
  time++;
  let sim = setTimeout(() => start(time), 30);
  if (time == 100) {
    bar.value = 0;
    let id = val;
    money++;
    document.getElementById("moneyValue").innerHTML = money;
    clearTimeout(sim);
    running = false;
  }
}
```

```css
#moneyValue::before {
  content: 'Money: ';
}
```

```html
<div id="moneyValue">0</div>
<progress id="progressBar1" value="0" max="100" style="width:150px;"></progress>
<button id="restart-button" class="plantBtn" onclick="onClickButton(0, this.id)">Plant Seed</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Break out the logic into another function that does the updating. Button that starts it on one method and the logic that updates the UI in another.

```js
let money = 0;
let running = false;

function start(time, val) {
  if (running == false) {
    running = true;
    console.log(running)
    runIt(time, val);
  } else if (running == true) {
    console.log("Already Growing!");
  };
}

function runIt(time, val) {
  let bar = document.getElementById('progressBar1');
  bar.value = time;
  time++;
  let sim = setTimeout(function () {runIt(time); }, 30);
  if (time == 100) {
    bar.value = 0;
    let id = val;
    money++;
    document.getElementById("moneyValue").innerHTML = money;
    running = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<progress id="progressBar1" value="0" max="100" style="width:150px;"></progress>
<button id="restart-button" class="plantBtn" onclick="start(0, this.id)">Plant Seed</button>

<div id="moneyValue"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an additional parameter that tells the function that the call is coming from the loop, and doesn't need to check if it's already running.

```js
let money = 0;
let running = false;

function start(time, val, isFromTimer) {
  if (running == false || isFromTimer == true) { // add check
    running = true;
    console.log(running)
    let bar = document.getElementById('progressBar1');
    bar.value = time;
    time++;
    let sim = setTimeout(() => start(time, val, true), 30); // tell function it's from the timer
    if (time >= 100) { // use more than or equal to instead
      bar.value = 0;
      let id = val;
      money++;
      //document.getElementById("moneyValue").innerHTML = money;
      clearTimeout(sim);
      running = false;
    }
  } else if (running == true) {
      console.log("Already Growing!");
  };
}
```

```html
<progress id="progressBar1" value="0" max="100" style="width:150px;"></progress>
<button id="restart-button" class="plantBtn" onclick="start(0, this.id)">Plant Seed</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use some CSS manipulation in your function once it is clicked?

`document.getElementById('restart-button').disabled = true;`

Then at the end of your function:

`document.getElementById('restart-button').disabled = false;`